# android studio sizing issue

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have buttons in my activity they are in correct size in editor but when i install my app on my device sizes are not correct.

## Screenshots

`Editor`

[image: one]

`Device`

[image: two]

## Code

`xml file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg2"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/White" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/itemButtons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="326dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="405dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="151dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:background="#76FF03"
                    android:text="@string/alphabetButton"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="151dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#2196F3"
                    android:text="@string/numberButton"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="151dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:background="#651FFF"
                    android:text="@string/colorsButton"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="151dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#FFEA00"
                    android:text="@string/shapes"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="151dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:background="#FF5252"
                    android:text="@string/bodyParts"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="151dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#C6FF00"
                    android:text="@string/furnitures"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="151dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#1DE9B6"
                    android:text="@string/cityParts"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1** 
you can achieve this by giving margin to your main `LinearLayout` as below 
 add `android:layout_marginStart="30dp"` and  `android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"` and set values according to your need

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="326dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="405dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp" //margin start
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp" //margin end change value as your need
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ...

     </LinearLayout>
```

**Solution 2**
 for making responsive as your requirment you can use `android:weightSum="1"`
as below.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        >
         <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            />

      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <LinearLayout

                android:id="@+id/itemButtons"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".8"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
             .... 
                 </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but would that be responsive due to devices screen size? you know it's fixed margin.

Comment: try solution 2 for responsive on every screen @mafortis

Answer (score 1):

You are giving fix sizes to buttons, give weight to buttons and set the width to zero it will be responsive

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

my view you give first three row in button width="0dp" and give weight="1".button divided in 2 part.